# variable pass on function jquery and Increments

Tags: jquery, variables, increment

I try to make a paging system in jquery.

POST send the number of the page

```
 setupLoadMore = function() {

        $('body').on('click','.loadmorebtn',function() {
            var page = 1; 
            function postProcessing(data) {
             var myArray = data;
             var $item =  [];
             var $items = $(null); 
              $items =   $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                           $item[i] = $($($.parseHTML(val)));
                           $items = $items.add($item[i]);
                           $grid.append($items);
                           $grid.shuffle('appended', $items);
                    });

            }
            $.ajax({
                      url: '/LoadMore',
                      type: 'POST',
                      data :   'rubr=' + page ,
                      dataType : 'json',
                      success:postProcessing,
                      async : true
                   });
                    page++;
                    alert(page);
        });
      },
```

Increments only once but no longer changes after he block on 2

The other problem is that it still remains in ajax 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var page = 1;` is in the scope of the function you run when the button it clicked.

If you want to preserve it between clicks, it needs to be declared in a wider scope than that function.